# Does CREATE OR REPLACE in BigQuery contribute towards a previous Partition Table's quota?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

We have a BigQuery query like:

```sql
  create or replace table `{project}`.`{dataset}`.`{table}`
  partition by date

  select {...}
```

If we run this query a few times in a day, we get an error:

> Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for Number of partition
> modifications to a column partitioned table. For more information, see
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

I've previously loaded partitioned tables with `bq load --replace` and don't remember having similar errors — suggesting the quota resets for the new table.

How does this work? Does `create or replace` use a cumulative quota for that table name, but `bq load --replace` resets the quota on each run?

Comment: Yeah, the quota is on table name. Replace or recreate wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Does `bq load --replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it expected behaviour for ‘CREATE OR REPLACE’ to contribute towards a previous/overwritten Partition Table's ‘maximum number of partition modifications’ quota?

- **Per-table quotas are bind to the table name**. 'CREATE OR REPLACE' does not change the table name so it will not reset the quota.

> Why then does a' bq load --replace' not affect the partition table quota?

- **'bq load --replace' does consume the quota as well**. Both 'load' and 'create or replace' can append data to multiple partitions. The number of partitions is counted as the number of [partition modifications](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables).